# Polygons which are completely overlapped by second polygon - QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I have multipolygon like here: [image]. And I have another, second polygon. Anyway I want to get only polygons which are completely overlapped by that second polygon. Intersection and clip in QGIS only cut the edges and that is, but like I said - I want only pieces (polygons) of this multipolygon which are completely overlapped by another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector > Research Tools > Select By Location

Use the geometry predicate "are within" to select one layer using the other.

Save selection as a new layer.

Comment: Thank you. :) I was looking for that, I think in QGIS2 was an option with the different name, but completely the same.